# Xcode сборка stdlibc++ с поддержкой C++11

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, c++11

Есть ли способ собрать проект под iOS используя библиотеку stdlibc++ (не libc++) с поддержкой C++11?

Comment: в build settings есть опция 'C++ Standard Library' - там можно libc++ поменять на libstdc++ (возможно надо в проекте создать .mm файл, чтобы эта опция появилась)

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky не уверен, что это тянет на ответ. :)